# Inno Setup AfterInstall procedure is executed too early, when installing MSI from Run section with /qn (silent) switch

Tags: inno-setup, windows-installer

After the execution of the `mariadb-10.2.11-winx64.msi` file, that installs the MariaDB 10.2.11 Server, I would like to make some changes on the **my.ini** file of the MariaDB 10.2.11 Server after it has been installed.

I have tried to use the `AfterInstall` parameter as shown bellow:

---

```
[Files]
Source: C:\Setup\Bin\mariadb-10.2.11-winx64.msi; DestDir: {tmp}; \
    Flags: ignoreversion promptifolder deleteafterinstall; Components: server

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\mariadb-10.2.11-winx64.msi; Parameters: /qn; \
    WorkingDir: {tmp}; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; AfterInstall: ConfigMyIni
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure ConfigMyIni;
var
  MyIni : String;
begin
  MyIni := ExpandConstant('{pf}\MariaDB 10.2\data\my.ini');
  if FileExists(MyIni) then
    begin
      if IniKeyExists('mysqld', 'character-set-server', MyIni) then
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'character-set-server', 'uft8', MyIni)
      else
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'character-set-server', 'uft8', MyIni);

      if IniKeyExists('mysqld', 'collation-server', MyIni) then
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'collation-server', 'uft8_bin', MyIni)
      else
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'collation-server', 'uft8_bin', MyIni);

      if IniKeyExists('mysqld', 'lower-case-table-names', MyIni) then
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'lower-case-table-names', '1', MyIni)
      else
        SetIniString('mysqld', 'lower-case-table-names', '1', MyIni);
    end;
end;
```

---

I have stepped through the script code and I have found that the `ConfigMyIni` procedure is executed before the end of the execution of the `mariadb-10.2.11-winx64.msi` file. The `my.ini` file does not exist at that moment. How can I force the `ConfigMyIni` procedure to be executed only after the end of the execution of the `mariadb-10.2.11-winx64.msi` file?

I have already read the help of Inno Setup and have searched for any answer on Stack Overflow but have not found any clue that I could follow to solve my problem.

Could anyone give some help on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a consequence of the `/qn` switch. With the switch, the top-level `msiexec` process delegates installation to a hidden subprocess and terminates itself immediately.

Consider using `/qb` or `/qb!` or similar, instead.

See [`msiexec` command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options).

Comment: Thank you. I have found that using the switch /qb!+ then the MariaBD Installer runs as a modal installer. Now the procedure ConfigMyIni, linked to the AfterInstall parameter, is executed only after the end of the execution of the MariaDB Installer.