# Run msi installer via paramiko and wait for the task to be done

Tags: python, synchronization, windows-installer, paramiko

I'm facing on some troubles here.

**The wish**
a python script that can update a third party software on all my factory machines.

**How i'm doing that**
I wrote a python script that's using Paramiko to ssh all the computers, copying required files and running .msi package on any succesfull connection.

**The problem**
Well, i'm not finding any way or method in order to wait msi process to be over and getting back any exit code.
I need to wait until installation is over and obtain a return code beacuse i need to copy hotfix files in x86 program installation directroy.
So, i tried the followings:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command("msiexec.exe /a msi_file_name.msi /qn")
```

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command("start /wait msiexec.exe /a msi_file_name.msi /qn")
```

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command("msi_file_name.msi /qn")
```

but noone of the above seems to wait for the installation to be over.

**My question to you guys**
I'm wondering if there's any way to run a msi and make the shell wait for the task to be over.
It will be fine both way, via python or via exec_command, using some cmd workaround.

Thanks,
**Hele**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Paramiko, nor even a Python question. That is a consequence of the `/qn` switch. With the switch, the top-level `msiexec` process delegates installation to a hidden subprocess and terminates itself immediately.

Consider using `/qb` or `/qb!` or similar, instead.

See [`msiexec` command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options).

---

*Copied from a similar question on Inno Setup:*
*[Inno Setup AfterInstall procedure is executed too early, when installing MSI from Run section with /qn (silent) switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47739100/850848)*